# how to display a pdf in iframe from a private storage in Laravel 6.9.0?

Tags: laravel, iframe

How to display a pdf file froma private folder "\storage\app\private" into a iframe? in Laravel version 6.9.0?

Please Help me thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to link your storage folder to the public folder with

`php artisan storage:link`

Then you can access the files in your storage folder with

`echo asset('storage/file.pdf');`

This generates a link to the file in your storage folder that can be used for the iframe.

Source: [Laravel Docs - File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem)

Comment: it will be visible to public, I thought I can get the file from a non public storage. Thanks for the answer

Comment: As far as i know you cannot serve a file unless it is in the public folder or it has a symbolic link to the public folder. I'd try to copy the file temporarily to the public folder and delete it after sending the reponse.